# How to do a search and replace for byte 92 and 96 in “.htm” files in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I have hundreds of `.htm' pages that were created years ago where most of the content was copied from Microsoft Word.

Unfortunately the pages contained word specific characters like the single curly quote `’` and long dash –. Their byte values are 92 and 96 respectively. I just want to replace them with the basic ACSII equivalents.

I am testing to search for the characters with grep before attempting a replace.

I have tried:

```
grep -n "’" *.htm
grep -n "\x92" *.htm
grep -n "[\x92]" *.htm
grep -P -n "[\x92]" *.htm
```

But they are not finding anything.
I made a small file with the contents and did a Hexdump:

> 0000000 20**92** 0d**96** 000a

You can see the hex values in bold (me). What is the correct way to find these?

Comment: If the files are UTF-8 encoded, you won't see `0x92` but `0xe28099` (U+2019) for curly quote and `0xe28093` (U+2013) for the en dash.

Comment: The files themselves to not appear to be utf-8 encoded, otherwise the hexdump should show that, but it is only showing that one byte. If I do LESS on it, it will show <92> where the quote would go. I assume hexdump is giving me the actual byte values? I reedit the file and left only those 2 symbols and hexdump gives me 0000000 9692 0a0d  (0a0d being crlf)

Comment: @Phunction Does [this help](https://superuser.com/a/199900/167207)? The file could be encoded with some crazy old school ecoding while `grep` is expecting UTF-8.

Comment: And in addition to Giacomo1968's comment, [Search and replace in multiple files using vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37424689/1115360) might be useful.

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is. Do browsers display the files incorrectly? and is this what you want to fix? The encoding of the characters in question is probably CP1250. Do the files themselves contain information about encoding? (e.g. `content="text/html; charset=…"`). `tr` is a standard tool to translate characters, but multi-byte characters, locale and such complicate things. If you are sure there are no multi-byte characters then `LC_ALL=C tr …` may be a solution.

Comment: It looks like 'sed' will work, it is able to find the value.

Comment: @Phunction, you might expand on using sed and make it an answer, which would also help others.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but it would be nice to know how to get grep to work, if it is even possible anyway.